# Php search with multiple fields

Tags: php, sql, search

I'm creating a php webpage search with mysql database ,

[image]

as you see on pic above  my html search form I'm passing three values through POST  .

PHP CODE:

```
<?php 
$search_name =$this->filter($_POST["name"]);

  $search_location=$this->filter($_POST["location"]);

  $search_speciality=$this->filter($_POST["category"]);

  $sql="SELECT * FROM pro
        WHERE ('pro_fname' LIKE '%".$search_name."%') OR ('pro_speciality' LIKE '%".$search_speciality."%') OR ('pro_location' LIKE '%".$search_location."%') and Pro_category='Doctor'";

  ?>
```

Problem is I always get  same result  only the first one on database .

even I let all fields  empty .

`Pro_category='Doctor'` I used it to separate result because I have two categories  Doctors and Pharmacies  and this search is only performed against DOCTORS

Comment: make sure u have empty field values in database and by making search empty it will get the row

Comment: i already have empty fields in database  but nothing affected

Comment: what are u getting after posting empty variables?

Comment: now i get them all  even if i chose speciality and  location  .  no filtration at all

Comment: echo  the query and test it in phpmyadmin and see the results

Comment: Is Pro_category supposed to be capitalized? You may also want to change the 'and' keyword to 'AND'. It makes sense that you could get a result back with empty fields so that's not the issue, could it be that it's not your query that's returning a single result but that the subsequent loop is only executing once/malformed?

Comment: i did  test on mysql  but it brought me all doctors  with different  locations

Comment: it seems  because when name is empty  and even  location is assigned   or speciality   it still brings all

Comment: $sql="SELECT * FROM pro
            WHERE (('pro_fname' LIKE '%".$search_name."%') OR ('pro_speciality' LIKE '%".$search_speciality."%') OR ('pro_wilaya' LIKE '%".$search_location."%')) AND (pro_category='Doctor')
            ";

thats my exact sql  copied from my editor  .

this is resr of the code  :

$roro=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
     $numOfUsersFound = mysqli_num_rows($roro);
    echo $numOfUsersFound;


     if ($numOfUsersFound>0){

       $row=mysqli_fetch_array($roro);
       $user_fname=$row["pro_fname"];
       $user_id=$row["id"];

Answer (score 0):

Try to enclosure your conditions properly, I mean

```
WHERE (condition1 or condition2 or condition3) and condition4
```

Comment: still have same problem  , filtration doesn't work  it brings all records

Comment: can you `var_dump($sql)` and post here?

Comment: string 'SELECT * FROM pro
            WHERE ('pro_fname' LIKE '%Marco%' OR  'pro_speciality' LIKE '%Dentist%' OR 'pro_location' LIKE '%South East%') AND (pro_category='Doctor')
            ' (length=181)

Comment: this example (marco, dentist , south east) brings nothing  even there is in database

Comment: thats may be stupid, but try to remove quotes around fields you use to filter, i.e.

Comment: WHERE (pro_fname LIKE '%Marco%') OR (pro_speciality LIKE '%Dentist%')

and so on

Comment: i removed  () and ''  so i got a better result   but still  when i choose location  still brings me  results with  different locations  those have  similar names  or specialities

Comment: it only takes  Name in consideration  if you type a name  it will give results with that name  , if you don't type a name and just choose speciality and location   it brings  everything .

what i want is  when i choose  speciality and location  it gives me  a doctors with  same speciality and location  

if i choose  just location  it gives me  all doctors  with all specialities  but  same  Location  

and if i be more specific and type name  with choosing both location and speciality i gives me   doctos with same name  location  and speciality